# How do I define Injective/Surjective functions in terms of sets and not the elements within them?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am in a Proof writing class and we are currently on functions. I have a good understanding of what it means to be injective or surjective in terms of elements in the set but I am having trouble coming up with a formal definition that just generalizes the definitions in terms of sets using an iff statement.

So if we have a function  $f: A\rightarrow B$

Would my statement be considered a proper theorem?

If $G\subseteq B$ then  $f: A\rightarrow B$  is surjective if and only if  $G=B$ and $f(f^{-1}( B)) = B$.

My reasoning here being that if our function is surjective everything in B has to have some pre-image in A. I am not sure If I need to say anything about A.

For Injective I came up with a similar theorem:

If $H\subseteq A$ then $f: A\rightarrow B$ is injective if and only if $A=H$ and $f(f^{-1}(A))=A$

My reasoning again being we need everything in our domain to have some image in B. So our domain subset must take on the whole set A.

Your help and knowledge would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the surjective definition, the $G$ is irrelevant. It just must verify that $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$, or simpler, just that $f(A)=B$.

For the injective definition, you can write it as:

$\forall H,N\subseteq A$, $f(H)=f(N) \implies H=N$.

Comment: When you say for all $G$ are we implying that $G$ is an arbitrary amount of subsets in $B$ similar to what you did in the injective definition?  I am having trouble understanding why we say for all  $H$, $N\subseteq A$ what is $N$ in this case?

Comment: $G$ is irrelevant in the formula for surjectivity: $f : A \to B$ is surjective iff $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$ or, equivalently and simpler, $f(A) = B$.

Comment: $H$ and $N$ can be any pair of subsets of the set $A$, and for it to be injective that condition must be verified for all $H,N\subseteq A$. The same applies to the surjectivity case, it isn't just enough if the condition is verified for one arbitrary subset, it must be verified in general. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @RobArthan Oh, I just noticed it. I'm editing now. Thanks.

Comment: @RobArthan Would that be the same case for injective then? $f: A\rightarrow B$ is injective iff $f(f^{-1}(A)) = A$ ? or do I need to say something about $A$'s subsets?

Comment: @Trap.Lord Almost. For injectivty, you could say that your $f$ is injective if and only if $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much.

Comment: If $f : A \to B$ is any function then $f^{-1}(f(A)) = A$. That equation tells you nothing about whether $f$ is injecdtive.

Comment: @RobArthan that doesn't verify in general. If there are two different points of $A$ with the same image, then $f^{-1}$ cant give two images for a same thing, so that equation does not verify if f is not injective.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso: if $f :A \to B$ isn't injective, $f^{-1}$ isn't a function but it's a relation and (with some abuse of notation), we write $f^{-1}(Y)$ for the set $\{x : A \mid f(x) \in Y\}$. Hence $f(f^{-1}(A)) = A$ regardless of whether $f$ is injective.

Comment: You could also say $f$ is injective if and only if for every subset $H \subseteq A$, we have $f^{-1}(f(H)) = H$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pair of categorical definitions:

A function $m:Y \to Z$ is injective, iff for all functions $a,b$ with codomain $Y$,

$$m \circ a = m \circ b \implies a = b$$

A function $e:X \to Y$ is surjective, iff for all functions $f,g$ with domain $Y$,

$$f \circ e = g \circ e \implies f=g$$

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear exactly what you are looking for, but the following are very useful "element-free" characterisations of injectivity and surjectivity:

1. $f : A \to B$  is injective iff it has a left inverse, i.e, iff there is a function $g: B  \to A$ such that $g \circ f = f$ (i.e., $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in A$).
2. $f : A \to B$  is surjective iff it has a right inverse, i.e, iff there is a function $g: B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = f$ (i.e., $f(g(y)) = y$ for all $y \in B$).

Comment: This was my original approach but my professor said that he wanted me to create a definition that uses the sets and not the composition of the functions. All I was given is we have a subset for A and a subset for B. So if I need to use them would it still hold that 

if $H\subseteq A$ and $G\subseteq B$ and we have $f: A\rightarrow B$ then:

$f$ is surjective $\iff$  $f(f^{-1}(H))  = H$ and

$f$ is injective $\iff$ $f^{-1}(f(G)) =G$ ?

Comment: In that case, Alejandro's **answer** fits the bill (despite a certain amount of confusion in the comments): the statement about injectivity needs you to quantify over subsets of $A$.

Comment: Sorry about that, this undergrad appreciates the help!